# Select subset of columns which minimise a criterion in R

Tags: r, combinatorics, minimize, rowsum

I have a sparse binary `data.frame` which looks like this

```r
set.seed(123)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(round(runif(40,0,0.9),0),5),ncol = 20))

#  > dat
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20
# 1   0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1
# 2   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
# 3   0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
# 4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 5   0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
# 6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 7   0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
# 8   0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
# 9   0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
# 10  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

I need to find the 3 columns which minimise the number of zeros obtained when I call `rowSums` on those columns.

Example:

```
 # > rowSums(dat[,1:3])
 # [1] 2 2 2 3 2 2 0 2 0 1
 # 
 # > rowSums(dat[,2:4])
 # [1] 3 2 3 3 1 2 1 1 0 1
```

Here when I call `rowSums` on the first 3 columns I get 2 zeros, while when I call `rowSums` on columns `2:4` I get only one `0`, so the second solution would be preferred.

Of course, I don't need the columns to be next to each other when I apply `rowSums`, so I need to explore all the possible combinations (ex: I want `rowSums` to consider also the case ov `V1+V5+V17`, ...), and if there are multiple "optimal" solutions, It's OK for me to just keep one of them.

Note that my real `data.frame` is 220.000 rows x 200 columns, so I need an efficient approach in terms of time/memory consumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most obvious solution, although likely won't scale very well:

```
which.min(combn(dat,3L,function(x) sum(rowSums(x)==0)));
## [1] 2
```

The output value of 2 can be thought of as a combination index. You can get the columns that belong to that combination by running `combn()` on the complete column index set of the input object and indexing out that particular combination of indexes:

```
cis <- combn(seq_along(dat),3L)[,2L];
cis;
## [1] 1 2 4
```

And then getting the column names is easy:

```
names(dat)[cis];
## [1] "V1" "V2" "V4"
```

You can get the number of zeroes in the solution as follows:

```
sum(rowSums(dat[,cis])==0);
## [1] 1
```

---

I've written a much faster solution in Rcpp.

To make the function more generic, I wrote it to take a logical matrix rather than a data.frame, with the design of finding the column combination with the fewest all-true rows. Thus, for your case, you can compute the argument as `dat==0`. I also parameterized the number of columns in the combination as a second parameter `r`, which will be 3 for your case.

```
library(Rcpp);
Sys.setenv('PKG_CXXFLAGS'='-std=c++11');

cppFunction('
    IntegerVector findColumnComboWithMinimumAllTrue(LogicalMatrix M,int r) {
        std::vector<int> rzFull(M.nrow()); std::iota(rzFull.begin(),rzFull.end(),0);
        std::vector<int> rzErase;
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> rzs(M.ncol(),std::vector<int>(M.nrow()));
        std::vector<std::vector<int>*> rzps(M.ncol());
        std::vector<int>* rzp = &rzFull;
        std::vector<int> com(r);
        int bestAllTrueCount = M.nrow()+1;
        std::vector<int> bestCom(r);
        int pmax0 = M.ncol()-r;
        int p = 0;
        while (true) {
            rzErase.clear();
            for (int rzi = 0; rzi < rzp->size(); ++rzi)
                if (!M((*rzp)[rzi],com[p])) rzErase.push_back(rzi);
            if (p+1==r) {
                if (rzp->size()-rzErase.size() < bestAllTrueCount) {
                    bestAllTrueCount = rzp->size()-rzErase.size();
                    bestCom = com;
                }
                if (com[p]==pmax0+p) {
                    do {
                        --p;
                    } while (p >= 0 && com[p]==pmax0+p);
                    if (p==-1) break;
                    ++com[p];
                    rzp = p==0 ? &rzFull : rzps[p-1];
                } else {
                    ++com[p];
                }
            } else {
                if (rzErase.empty()) {
                    rzps[p] = rzp;
                } else {
                    rzs[p].clear();
                    int rzi = -1;
                    for (int ei = 0; ei < rzErase.size(); ++ei)
                        for (++rzi; rzi < rzErase[ei]; ++rzi)
                            rzs[p].push_back((*rzp)[rzi]);
                    for (++rzi; rzi < rzp->size(); ++rzi)
                        rzs[p].push_back((*rzp)[rzi]);
                    rzp = rzps[p] = &rzs[p];
                }
                ++p;
                com[p] = com[p-1]+1;
            }
        }
        IntegerVector res(bestCom.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i)
            res[i] = bestCom[i]+1;
        return res;
    }
');
```

Here's a demo on your example input:

```
set.seed(123L);
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(round(runif(40,0,0.9),0),5),ncol=20L));
findColumnComboWithMinimumAllTrue(dat==0,3L);
## [1] 1 2 4
```

And here's a full-size test, which takes almost 10 minutes on my system:

```
set.seed(1L); NR <- 220e3L; NC <- 200L;
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1,NR*NC,T),NR,NC));
system.time({ findColumnComboWithMinimumAllTrue(dat==0,3L); });
##    user  system elapsed
## 555.641   0.328 556.401
res;
## [1] 28 64 89
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, you've been very helpful and I would have never come to a solution like yours. Your function works with `r=3`, but unfortunately it is too slow with `r=5` which is the parameter I need. I didn't write it in the question because I didn't think it would be critical, but in fact it does, as with `r=3` we have ~1,3 million possible combinations, while with `r=5 `this number goes up to ~2,5 **billion** (almost 2000 times bigger). Sorry for the mistake. If you see a way to improve the function, that would be great. Otherwise, thanks anyway!

Comment: @hellter You're very welcome. Out of curiosity, have you been able to find any solution that can handle the `r=5` case in a reasonably short period of time?

Comment: I'm thinking it throug, but I didn't come to a solution yet, and I can't see an easy way to do this..